# Custom Link Provider in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: link-manager

I am upgrading from Sitecore 9.1 to Sitecore 9.3. I have a `CustomLinkProvider` class which derives from `LinkProvider` which is obsolete in Sitecore 9.3.

What is the replacement for this in Sitecore 9.3?

Answer (score -2):

Custom link provider working has been changed in Sitecore 9.3. You can get more details at the following blogs:

- https://adapty.com/blog/sitecore-9-3-custom-link-provider/
- https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/build-item-and-media-urls.html

Comment: Can you add some information from the blogs to make the answer less "link-only"?

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please provide detail so that the answer can be understood without leaving the SSE site.